# Pressed shutter button without advancing the film, did i create a double exposure?

Tags: film, 35mm, shutter, camera, double-exposure

I’ve recently bought a film camera, the lomo aquapix ( it can be considered a toy camera )

I’m new to film photography.

I took the a picture and then accidentally pressed the shutter button again without advancing the the film by using the advance lever, I did not hear anything.

Will it overwrite on the film ? ( Create a double exposure ? )

Answer (score 4):

Usually an analogue camera does not create a double exposure when pressing the shutter again, without advancing the film. The film advance process also cocks the shutter mechanism. So if the film isn't advanced, nothing happens.

There are cameras that have a special feature to do double exposures, by allowing you to re-cock the shutter without advancing the film. The picture would then feature both exposures overlaying. This can be used in creative ways.

With film, it would not overwrite the image, but it may look as if, when your first picture was very dark and the second very light.

Comment: Some very old film cameras might not have double exposure protection due to shutter cocking and film transport being completely independent mechanisms. However, this is about really old (early folder style) cameras....

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you mean by this sentence: "With film, it would not overwrite the image, but it may look as if, when your first picture was very dark and the second very light."

Comment: This is a very cheep and simple plastic camera, on some other cheep and simple plastic cameras the shutter will open every time regardless of whether or not the film lever has been advanced. It may simply have a spring that resets the shutter.  It lacks the monitory investment to engineer this function.

Comment: @rackandboneman I just spent some time using an RB67, something I wouldn't call "really old" and that has separate film and cocking mechanisms - and I managed to get several unintentional double exposures.  Also while my Holga 35mm *does* interlock the film transport and shutter mechanisms, my Holga Medium format does not.

Comment: @osullic it would not "overwrite" as in the modern sense of digitally overwriting an image (i.e. completely replacing the old image with a new image). It would however, do an analogue "additive" overwrite where the new image would be added to the original image (i.e. a double exposure).

Comment: @FreeMan thanks, I know what a double exposure in film photography is. My problem is with the wording and explanation as quoted.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes you have made a double exposure, but i am not 100% sure. 
*There is nothing you can do about it if you have, Maybe it will be a happy accident and you will have an interesting image.*

Because it is a cheep and simple plastic camera it may re-expose the film ( *create a double exposure* ) **but** you would be able to hear and feel if the shutter was released

I have the Lomo Diana F and it has a shutter that fires every time you press the shutter release button, **time after time after time with out ever advancing the film**. It has the shutter lever on the lens itself so it is slightly different then yours.

I would suggest that after this roll of film you try it with no film in the camera.

Keep the back of the camera open and advance the lever, press the shutter button while you look through the lens from the back side and watch it operate, then press it again WITHOUT advancing the lever and see if the shutter fires again. sense i do not know for sure how the shutter on this camera works so i can not answer definitively.

**Try to learn as much as you can about your camera BEFORE you start shooting film to avoid wasting money.**